# Python: Is there a way to get all the column names in a new column if a condition is met (e.g. "Yes")

Tags: python

| unique id | col1 | col2 | col3 | New Col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes | No | Yes | col1, col3 |
| 2 | No | Yes | No | col2 |
| 3 | Yes | Yes | No | col1, col2 |
| 4 | No | No | No |  |

I was wondering how I can get the respective column names if "Yes" to a new column call "New Col".

Comment: Just to be clarified: do you want the results be stored as a raw string like `'col1, col2'`, or a list listing out the matching columns like `['col1', 'col2']`?

Comment: I want the results to return as a string separated by commas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply a list comprehension to each row to return the column names where the value in the column is 'Yes'.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'unique id': [1,2,3,4],
        'col1': ['Yes','No','Yes','No'],
        'col2': ['No','Yes','Yes','No'],
        'col3': ['Yes','No','No','No']}
df = pd.DataFrame (data)

df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda row:','.join([col for col in df.columns[1:] if row[col]=='Yes']) , axis=1)

print(df)

""" OUTPUT
   unique id col1 col2 col3    new_col
0          1  Yes   No  Yes  col1,col3
1          2   No  Yes   No       col2
2          3  Yes  Yes   No  col1,col2
3          4   No   No   No
"""
```

Comment: Peak pandas has been achieved

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`pandas.DataFrame.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) to solve the problem. It returns each row as a *Series*, which allows you to do such comparison.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'unique id': [1,2,3,4],
    'col1': ['Yes','No','Yes','No'],
    'col2': ['No','Yes','Yes','No'],
    'col3': ['Yes','No','No','No']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

new_col = []
# We only need the Series part of returning tuples from df.iterrows
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    # Get indices that match the desired condition
    match_columns = row[row == 'Yes'].index.tolist()
    new_col.append(match_columns)
    
# Assign the result back to the table (DataFrame) as a new column
df['New Col'] = new_col
```

Now `df` is what you want. Although I would suggest not using space for a column name (just for coding convention), so `df['new_col'] = new_col` may be better. I did that just to meet your original needs.

Answer (score 0):

this is one solution, although I am sure it's not ideal. Please ask for any details.

```
# import pandas and make fake data
import pandas as pd
data = {'unique id': [1,2,3,4],
        'col1': ['Yes','No','Yes','No'],
        'col2': ['No','Yes','Yes','No'],
        'col3': ['Yes','No','No','No']}
df = pd.DataFrame (data)

# now find all locations where each column contains 'Yes'
mask1 = df['col1']=='Yes'
mask2 = df['col2']=='Yes'
mask3 = df['col3']=='Yes'

# now build the new desired output column using string manipulation
output = []
for m1,m2,m3 in zip(mask1,mask2,mask3): # for each row of the dataframe
    contains = [] # collect the components of the string in the new column
    if m1: 
        contains.append('col1')
    if m2:
        contains.append('col2')
    if m3:
        contains.append('col3')
    output.append(', '.join(contains)) # build the string
    
# and add the new column of data to the dataframe
df['New Col'] = output
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea:

1. Define a function `get_filtered_colnames` we can apply to row by row. Let this function return the names of columns where the value in that row is 'Yes'.
2. Apply `get_filtered_colnames` to every row in `df`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Creating the dataframe.
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((4, 3)), columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df['col1'] = ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No']
df['col2'] = ['No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No']
df['col3'] = ['Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No']

# Defining a function that can be applied row by row to the dataframe.
def get_filtered_colnames(row, colnames):
    # Extracting the column indices where the column contains 'Yes'.
    filtered_idxs = np.where(row == 'Yes')[0]

    # Column names where the column containes 'Yes'.
    filtered_colnames = [colnames[filtered_idx] for filtered_idx in filtered_idxs]

    return filtered_colnames

# Applying the above function row by row (hence, axis=1). Passing col names as parameter.
df['New Col'] = df.apply(get_filtered_colnames, colnames=df.columns.tolist(), axis=1)
print(df)
```

This gives the following desired output:

```
    col1   col2   col3           New Col
0  'Yes'   'No'  'Yes'  ['col1', 'col3']
1   'No'  'Yes'   'No'          ['col2']
2  'Yes'  'Yes'   'No'  ['col1', 'col2']
3   'No'   'No'   'No'                []
```

Edit: You can follow @kevinkayaks comment if you want the output as `str` instead of `list`.

Comment: that's not the desired output tho : ) 
Try `filtered_colnames = ', '.join([colnames[filtered_idx] for filtered_idx in filtered_idxs])
`